How to expand branches of a forest tree
I am trying to draw a stemma codicum of a critical edition using the package forest - after the first step of drawing all the branches I now need to expan the branches before adjusting all the lengths. Can anyone tell me how to expand only some of them (for example I would need theta to the more left and beta more to the right)? Thanks
\documentclass[border=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\forestset{
empty nodes/.style={
for tree={calign=fixed edge angles},
delay={where content={}{shape=coordinate,anchor=north}{}}
}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
[$\omega$[$\phi$[$\theta$[C][D][Fl][E][$\chi$[O][Ve]][F]][Q(?)][M]][$\beta$[$\gamma$[W][$\sigma$[V][Z]][B(?)]][$\delta$[$\varepsilon$[P][U][$\eta$[R][T]]][S]]]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}


You can add explicit s sep values on particular nodes of the tree to expand them:
\documentclass[border=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\forestset{
empty nodes/.style={
for tree={calign=fixed edge angles},
delay={where content={}{shape=coordinate,anchor=north}{}}
}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
[$\omega$,s sep=1cm[$\phi$,s sep=1cm[$\theta$[C][D][Fl][E][$\chi$[O][Ve]][F]][Q(?)][M]][$\beta$,s sep=1cm[$\gamma$[W][$\sigma$[V][Z]][B(?)]][$\delta$[$\varepsilon$[P][U][$\eta$[R][T]]][S]]]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}



that's exactly what I needed! Thank you very much!

This is a modification of Alan Munn's answer. I would consider changing two things. First, I would align the middle child's edge with the parent when the number of children is odd. Second, if you are drawing many of these and/or they are highly complex, I would use s sep' rather than s sep when provided an explicit dimension such as 1cm. The result of this second change will be identical output, but the tree will be processed faster.
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
% \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/717680/ addaswyd o ateb Alan Munn: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/717669/ i gwestiwn Andrea: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/717656/
\forestset{%
  align middle of odd/.style={%
    before typesetting nodes={%
      where={ > Ow+P {n children}{isodd(##1)} }
      {%
        for n/.process={%
          Ow+P {n children}{(##1+1)/2} 
          {%
            calign with current edge,
          }%
        },
      }{},
    },
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  align middle of odd,
  [$\omega$,s sep'=1cm[$\phi$,s sep'=1cm[$\theta$[C][D][Fl][E][$\chi$[O][Ve]][F]][Q(?)][M]][$\beta$,s sep'=1cm[$\gamma$[W][$\sigma$[V][Z]][B(?)]][$\delta$[$\varepsilon$[P][U][$\eta$[R][T]]][S]]]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}

I'm not going to compete with Alan's image, though. My image conversion is currently so poor, the result will look terrible regardless of the output to PDF. (I need to figure out convert or pdfimages re. quality.)


I didn't know that s sep' was faster. Good to know. I've added a nice image to go with the nice answer. :)

@AlanMunn Thank you very much. s sep' avoids pgfmath and just does a direct TeX assignment, which is why it has to be an explicit dimension. prooftrees uses a slew of these tricks, many of which are in forest as a result of prooftrees being so slow. So I ought to know ;).
